# In Azure Api Management Developer Portal, how can I add the ability for the user of the portalt o download the OpenAPI Definitions?

Tags: swagger, openapi, azure-api-management

How can I add a similar button in the "new" Azure API Management Developer Portal?  [image]

Is the swagger available in a specific url?

I have tried to find documentation on it, but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

Also the new Azure API Management Developer Portal has such a button:

[image]

Comment: Where can I find it when the default template is not used?

Comment: @HoumanMohebbi What is the `default template`? You can find the button below each API Name.